# Reading parts of a file and writing it to single unsigned char

Tags: c, file, pointers, fread

I want to read from few parts of a file and than output it as one unsigned char.
This is a simplified version of this:

```
void loadPartsOfFile (const char *filename, unsigned char **output)
{
    *output = malloc(333);

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); 
    fread(*output, 1, 111, file);
    fseek(file, 10254, SEEK_SET);
    fread(*output, 1, 222, file);

    fclose(file);
}
```

Second fread just overwrites what first added to output. Is there a way to append second data stream to output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void loadPartsOfFile (const char *filename, unsigned char **output)
{
    *output = realloc(*output, 333);

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); 
    fread(*output, 1, 111, file);
    fseek(file, 10254, SEEK_SET);
    fread(*output+111, 1, 222, file);

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! By the way is there a way to add to output some data like: char data[2] = {0xD5,0x48};

Comment: Yes, of course. Just increment the size for realloc by 2, and do a `memcpy(*output+some_offset, data, 2);` somewhere. If the data is inserted before the other two members, these will have to be shifted up too.

Answer (score 2):

Just increment `*output` until the end of the previous read, i. e. `*output + 111`.